# dbContext.SaveChanges() not updating single row as expected in .NET

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linq

I have 2 tables: `TableA` and `TableB` in MySQL on which I am trying to do some CRUD operations in .NET. I have written a function to insert a new row in `TableA` followed by updating a single row in `TableB`. The incoming request consists of an `incommingID` parameter. The insert command works as expected but the update command on `TableB` dosen't do anything. It doesn't even give any error. The method is given below:

```cs
public int SomeMethod(int incommingID)
{
    MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
    TableAModel rowA = new TableAModel
    {
        // ...data to be inserted
    }
    db.TableA.Add(rowA);

    var query = from tableData in db.TableB
                where tableData.id == incommingID
                select tableData;
    var rowToBeUpdated = query.SingleOrDefault();

    if(rowToBeUpdated != null)
    {
        // isAccepted is false for all rows and is to be set true for this particular id but 
        // when updated, the changes don't reflect and the row still has isAccepted as false.
        rowToBeUpdated.isAccepted = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return incommindID;
}
```

I even tried wrapping the code with a try...catch but it didn't throw any errors. What is the reason that `TableA` insert is working as expected but `TableB` update isn't working?

Comment: The code seems correct and should fail when the update doesn't actually save `rowToBeUpdated`. How do you check the actual update? Also, if this isn't the actual code maybe you should show that code nonetheless.

Comment: I am checking the update in SQL table in SSMS. This is the actual code... I am just trying something new

Comment: Then I can only conclude that `isAccepted` is not mapped correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to ask enityframework for update the change also.
As you added tableA

```
db.TableA.Add(rowA);
```

You need to ask entityframework to update the changes too.

```
db.Entry(rowToBeUpdated).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: Please never post mere suggestions as answers. In this case it's also wrong.